# dvipng puts page numbers at the end of png files produced when displaying latex fragments in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, images

I can produce latex and dvi files from latex fragments in org files. I have dvipng chosen as the way to produce an image file.  Unfortunately, it seems like dvipng puts the page number at the end of the file name (so produces file1.png from file.dvi), therefore emacs can not find the appropriate png file to display.  It is looking for file.png.  Suggestions?

Comment: You can do `dvipng file.dvi -o file.png`. What is the value of the image converter in the `dvipng` section of the variable `org-preview-latex-process-alist`? That's where this problem is taken care of. Find the value of the variable and add it  to your question.